# Eslint rule to set self closing tag mandatory for angular component

Tags: html, angular, eslint

Is there a rule in eslint that set the self closing tag mandatory for angular component ?

It seems the rule exists in [react](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/self-closing-comp.md)

```
"react/self-closing-comp": ["error", {
  "component": true,
  "html": true
}]
```

And [vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/html-self-closing.html)

```
  "vue/html-self-closing": ["error", {
    "html": {
      "void": "never",
      "normal": "always",
      "component": "always"
    },
    "svg": "always",
    "math": "always"
  }]
```

I tried to add this [rule](https://yeonjuan.github.io/html-eslint/docs/rules/require-closing-tags/) but it does not work, even on html.

```
"html-eslint/require-closing-tags": [
  "error",
  {
    "self-closing": "always"
  }
],
```

I'm expecting this to be an error

```
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
```

when no child is in the balise, and

```
<app-my-component/>
```

to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is in `@angular-eslint`:

```
"@angular-eslint/template/prefer-self-closing-tags": [
  "error"
]
```

See the [dedicated doc](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin-template/docs/rules/prefer-self-closing-tags.md).